# Colour of photos in different browsers?

Tags: image-processing, cross-browser, photos

I've just put some photos up online and I noticed that they photos appear to be a different colour in Firefox and Safari to IE and Chrome... Any ideas on what the issue could be? Due the browsers interpreter colours spaces differently or something?

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They interpret color spaces differently because some browsers ignore ICC color profiles that are part of the images themselves.  Safari and Firefox 3+ don't however, though Firefox needs to be configured to enable it.

Here's a related link: http://www.gballard.net/psd/go_live_page_profile/embeddedJPEGprofiles.html

Comment: Is there a trick to saving the photos so that they all look the same... firefox and safari have it right and the others look just really bad... if it helps I exported the photos using lightroom. thanks for the help

Comment: Unfortunately, Lightroom always saves an ICC Profile with the image so there's no way around it from that product alone.  http://www.computer-darkroom.com/lr_colour/lightroom-colour.htm  Using photoshop you could disable color management.  Another thing to consider is that even without color management different types of displays will display color in different ways, making the differences even more noticeable.

Comment: Ok if I can't get rid of the ICC Profile in lightroom (this is a big pain in the bum if you can't), are you saying that I am best to save using photoshop?

Comment: Yes: http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/10.0/help.html?content=WSF8890E7B-90A1-4a11-859E-0BCE0D1A088B.html.  I know the attention and concern for color you must have having been in the print/prepress industry years ago.  It's quite a challenge.

Comment: Ya, the difference in colour isn't small - i'm not being picky, its like the photos don't have any orange in IE and chrome... If in photoshop I save the photos out using 'save for web' will this fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that png format especially differs cross browser wise. When I noticed this, I converted to jpg and it resolved it.